# Call script in thread with another python3 interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-venv

I have a script, which I execute with one interpreter (from one venv). I need to call another script in a thread with another interpreter (also venv), but for some reason it gives me

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module_name'
```

For now I do it like this:

```
th = threading.Thread(target=os.system, args=(params,))
th.start()
```

I tried to install callee interpreter's dependencies to the caller dependencies.

I have also tried to add

```
source /path/to/venv/bin/activate;
```

to `params`, but neither did not help me.

I also tried to do

```
sys.path.append('/path/to/the/caller/script')
```

But there were no effect. Any ideas how to fix this?

upd. Added example:

```
# caller.py
import threading
import os

th = threading.Thread(target=os.system, args=('/path/to/flask/app.py',))
th.start()
```

---

```
# callee.py
#!/usr/bin/python3

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

If you execute caller.py with pure python3 interpreter you will have

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/path/to/flask/app.py", line 3, in <module>
from flask import Flask
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

because there is no flask in the caller venv

Comment: You will need to provide more code, not just rough single lines of what you're running. Please post a complete and minimal piece of code for reproducing your issue.

Comment: As an overall comment, you probably want to use subprocess, and not os.system inside a thread (https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) You also don't need to activate the other venv if you can get a path to the venv's python executable.

Comment: @EhsanKia, I have edited the question

Comment: @EhsanKia, tried `subprocess.call('/path/to/flask/app.py')`. Result is still the same

Comment: Try doing '/path/to/venv/bin/python /path/to/flask/app.py' instead.